# Unable to loop through my postman response

Tags: arrays, postman

I have this json respone from postman
I want to write a test to return failure if key "value" in the array is < 50.

It would loop through the array once the condition is not met it fails

I have tried this

```
pm.test('Matches value', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json(), (arrItem) => {
        if (arrItem.persID === 'personID_2') {
            throw new Error(`Array contains ${arrItem.persID}`)
        }
    })
});
```

My response

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "title": "Maids",
      "subTitle": null,
      "description": null,
      "featured": false,
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "title": "AA",
          "subTitle": "AA",
          "thumbnail": "AA",
          "priceStartingAt": {
            "value": 50,
            "baseCurrency": "USD",
            "exchangeEnabled": true,
            "exchangeRates": {
              "aed": 3.672973
            }
          },
          "categories": [
            "Activity"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "title": "BB",
          "subTitle": "BB",
          "thumbnail": "BB",
          "priceStartingAt": {
            "value": 20.01,
            "baseCurrency": "USD",
            "exchangeEnabled": true,
            "exchangeRates": {
              "aed": 3.672973
            }
          },
          "categories": [
            "Activity"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

In this case the test should fail because the value in the second array is 20.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure *where* you copied that code from but it was never going to work as all the references relate to a different response body.

To keep the same convention and have the `throw new Error` in there you could do this:

```
pm.test('Value is not below 50', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json().groups[0].items, (arrItem) => {
        if (arrItem.priceStartingAt.value < 50) {
            throw new Error(`Array contains ${arrItem.priceStartingAt.value}`)
        }
    })
});
```

Or you could just check if the items are not below `50` like this.

```
pm.test('Value is not below 50', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json().groups[0].items, (arrItem) => {
            pm.expect(arrItem.priceStartingAt.value).to.not.be.below(50)
    })
});
```

Comment: that was my bad i copied that code and modified it to fit into mine. I just noticed i accidentally placed the non edited version into the question. This was what i did initially                                                                                                          
           pm.test('val less than 50', () => {
    _.each(jsonData(groups[0].items[0].priceStartingAt.value), (arrItem) => {
        if (arrItem < 50) {
            throw new Error('Array contains ');
        }
    });
});

Comment: Thanks a lot Danny. Yes it worked just ran it. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, if you wanted to accept this as the answer that would be cool :)